# how to read first two columns from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have task to read csv file using python.

Task is to read first two columns from csv file.

csv file looks like

```
car name,miles/gallon,cylinders,displacement,horsepower,weight,acceleration,model year,origin
"chevrolet chevelle malibu",18,8,307,130,3504,12,70,1
"buick skylark 320",15,8,350,165,3693,11.5,70,1
"plymouth satellite",18,8,318,150,3436,11,70,1
```

my code:

```
import csv
list2 = []
with open("mylist.csv") as f:
    for row in f:
        list2.append(row[0])
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please don't tell me this is a homework problem.

Comment: @connectyourcharger I have updated my question.

Comment: @barbsan I am trying to read first two columns not specific single column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **pandas** `read_csv()` has the built-in ability to specify which columns of a file to read. Just provide `usecols` with a single integer value or a list of column indices:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('~/file.csv', usecols=[0,1], header=0)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                    car name  miles/gallon
0  chevrolet chevelle malibu            18
1          buick skylark 320            15
2         plymouth satellite            18
```

Answer (score 0):

To read the first two columns, use slicing to append a list rather than a scalar. Since you are using the `csv` module, you can use `csv.reader` to simplify your logic:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

x = '''car name,miles/gallon,cylinders,displacement,horsepower,weight,acceleration,model year,origin
"chevrolet chevelle malibu",18,8,307,130,3504,12,70,1
"buick skylark 320",15,8,350,165,3693,11.5,70,1
"plymouth satellite",18,8,318,150,3436,11,70,1'''

list2 = []
# replace StringIO(x) with open('mylist.csv', 'r')
with StringIO(x) as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    headers = next(reader)[:2]
    for row in reader:
        list2.append(row[:2])

print(headers, list2, sep='\n')

# ['car name', 'miles/gallon']
# [['chevrolet chevelle malibu', '18'], ['buick skylark 320', '15'], ['plymouth satellite', '18']]
```

To read the second column as an integer, you can modify your logic:

```
list2.append([row[0], int(row[1])])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **pandas** like this way-

```
import os
import pandas as pd
filename = os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/mylist.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=1, index_col=None, names=['car name','miles/gallon','cylinders','displacement','horsepower','weight','acceleration','model year','origin'])
df = df[['car name','miles/gallon']]
print(df)
```

Comment: you don't need to use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` if you just use a relative path like: `mylist.csv`

Comment: @AbhinavBhandari Yes agreed.